# Focus an element given an html input tag? Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, input

I have an html tag "**tabbedCell"** returned which can be viewed below:

```
<input type="text" data-row-id="12630" class="edit numeric ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-field="May" value="135" style="position: relative; cursor: cell;">
```

I'm trying to set focus on this element, however I have confirmed the focused element is undefined after setting focus. Any suggestions?

EDIT: There are multiple inputs on my page so the answers would not work. I need to focus this specific input element if multiple exist.

```
console.log(tabbedCell)
$(tabbedCell).focus();
console.log(($(':focus')[0]));
```

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/mb9xg2r1/1/

Comment: You are not selecting the element properly, are you? you are saying $(tabbedCell) but such value doesn't exist on your input element?

Comment: I also verified that it works fine if I get the reference properly.  You'll need to share more code because the problem doesn't lie in what you've shared here.

Comment: I have added more context. Unfortunately, the solutions assuming that is the only input tag on the page.

Comment: There is context missing here. Where is `tabbedCell` coming from? Where is your JS located, relative to the input Element? Are you sure that the input is rendered before your JS is executed? Otherwise you need wait for a DOM-readiness event...

Comment: tabbedCell is the input element. Yes, I can confirm my input is rendered before my JS executed as it logs the input element, if not it would be undefined.

Comment: @rahulchawla I've updated my jsfiddle to have multiple inputs, it still works: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/mb9xg2r1/4/

Comment: It seems like the whole problem you're having is with getting the correct input into `tabbedCell`, not with focusing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add id="sample_input"

```
<input type="text" id="sample_input" data-row-id="12630" class="edit numeric ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-field="May" value="135" style="position: relative; cursor: cell;">
```

This is how you focus 
# -> Means id

```
$("#sample_input").focus();
```

Edit: Since you dont want to add another id use this:

```
$("input[data-row-id=12630]").focus();
```

Edit 2: like this

```
$("input[data-row-id=12630][data-field=May]").focus();
```

Comment: I cannot add another id, is there a way to do it by taking data-row-id & data-field attributes into account?

Comment: Updated the answer take a look

Comment: is there anyway to take the  data-field="May" into account? as theres multiple inputs with the same data-row-id.

Comment: Closest solution! I ended up appending data-field to the data-row-id so it would be unique and thus focusable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use an ID or Class of the element instead, like here you can use "edit".

```
$(".edit").focus();
```

Comment: This does not work I have multiple inputs with the same id/class - is it possible to distinguish based on data-row-id /data-field

Comment: This element does not have an id. Use a unique id for this task and then focus on it. And btw, same ID should not be used in multiple elements, classes can be used.